# why the term key in on duplicate statements?

Tags: mysql

I am new to `mysql` and was reading about on `duplicate key update`.  The statement we generally write would be something like this

```
insert into table (col1,col2) values(1,1) on duplicate key update col2=1;
```

Assuming col1 to be `primary`.

My understanding of this is statement is that if there is duplicate value in col1 the respective statement updates col2 with 1.  My question is why do we use the term "`key`" in this statement? As it is understood that the statement updates only when there is a `primary key violation`.  Are there any other parameters or function which we can use with `duplicate`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL updates either if there is a *primary* or a *unique* key violation. The [manual covers it quite extensively](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in a separate chapter with examples:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row.

The term *key* is used as part of the syntax definition. The term is afaik only available when performing `INSERT`-statements. If you insert data by any other means (I can only think of [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) right now), other mechanisms come into place.

Comment: hi ..  are there any other terms which we can use with on duplicate?

Comment: see my answer (just revised it). "key" it is just part of the syntax and there are not many other ways to insert data (i've covered load data in my reply) - hence not many possibilities on how to force duplicate data.

Answer (score 1):

There are no other options with this command. In  additional I want to say that you can rewrite the statement in this way -

INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES(1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(col2);

Also you can use:

- an [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) statement with IGNORE keyword to ignore errors.
- a [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) statement to replace records by unique key.

In other words INSERT+ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE works like an INSERT and REPLACE in one statement. And one more thing - the INSERT+ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement has big advantage, it does not remove records on updating; the REPLACE statement removes and then inserts new record.

Comment: hi .. my question was why do we use the term "key".  Does it have any significance ? are there any other terms which we can use with on duplicate?